# TextView not Found

Tags: android, textview

This is driving me absolutely crazy and Im not sure what is going on.
I have an xml layout with a TextView within a clickable RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bg_section"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/almost_black"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="goToBG"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Go To B.G."
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bg_arrow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="-10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_icon" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/current_bg_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/bg_arrow"
                android:text="3"
                android:textColor="@color/holo_blue"
                android:textSize="22sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Now in my code I try to update the textview "current_bg_count"

```
private void updateBGCount(){
    try{
        RelativeLayout bgSection = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.bg_section);
        TextView bgCountTV = (TextView) bgSection.getChildAt(2);
        bgCountTV.setText(tempBG.size());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Logger.d(TAG, "exception in updateBGCount");
    }
}
```

This gives a ResourceNotFountException on the line where I setText although the RelativeLayout is found without a problem. Even when I try finding it just by id like this:

```
TextView bgCountTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_bg_count)
bgCountTV.setText(tempBG.size());
```

it gives the same error. 
All the other views in the layout are found easily and updated just fine. Only this one TextView is giving me the problem. Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project? "Project --> Clean..."

Comment: Try cleaning your project.

Comment: What does tempBG refer to?  Is that an array?

Comment: Yes, this hasn't fixed it!

Comment: tempBG is an ArrayList

Comment: Use Tostring() in bgCountTV.setText(tempAmenities.size());
Don't Expect too much automatic conversion from Eclipse

Comment: Be sure to mark the codeMagic's answer as correct.

Comment: @Charlie I don't think you want any automatice conversion here since that is a valid method...just misused in this case

Comment: @codeMagic i meant that ,may be there is no method overloading

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert your `size` of the `ArrayList` to a `String` at this line

```
 setText(tempBG.size())
```

Since `tempBG.size()` returns an `int` then `setText()` is looking for a resource with the `id` of whatever that returns. You are using [this setText(ResId int) method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29) which is used for if you have a `string resource` that you want to use to set the text.

So change it to

```
setText(String.valueOf(tempBG.size()));
```

Comment: It was really something so simple. I can't believe it. Thanks!

Comment: Has to be an issue with the setText as that is the only common denominator between using getChild() and findViewById() attempts which neither worked.

Comment: It is that simple but don't worry, happens quite often ;)

Comment: Accept it as an answer, if it solved your problem. Saying Thanks is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your `tempBG.size()` to string like this

```
bgCountTV.setText(""+tempBG.size());
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

Are you using eclipse? Check there is no errors and warning in your project. Sometimes there are errors in xml that let you compile, but doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

the Problem is with this code

```
bgCountTV.setText(tempBG.size());
```

`tempBG.size()` this code is returning an **int** value which it is assuming as **string** Resource id  something like R.string.VARIABLE_NAME coz it have a corresponding int value which TextView is assuming as id

What you can do

```
 bgCountTV.setText(tempBG.size()+"");
```

OR

```
 bgCountTV.setText(String.ValueOf(tempBG.size()));
```

OR

```
 bgCountTV.setText(tempBG.size().toString());
```